# function pointer and struct

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

I was reading about structures in c, and came across this code. I was hoping somebody could help me break this code down and understand what its' doing.

```
struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
{
    struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    assert(who != NULL);

    who->name = strdup(name);
    who->age = age;
    who->height = height;
    who->weight = weight;

    return who;
};
```

Specifically, this is the portion of the code that I don't understand

```
*Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
```

Comment: The `*` is related to the type, not the function. You should read it as `struct Person *` and  `Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)`. So the function returns a pointer to `struct Person`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `*` is related to the type, not the function.

You should read it as `struct Person *` returned by `Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)`.

So the function returns a pointer to `struct Person`.

it's a common:

```
 [return type] func([arguments])
```

If you wanted to write a function pointer, you would have:

```
 [return type] (*func_pointer_name)([arguments])
```

i.e.

```
 struct Person * (*person_create_p)(char *, int, int, int) = &Person_create;
```

Comment: Ah, I see. So the function portion of the code takes precedence over the struct, which makes the code read, as, function returns this structure. Great, thanks for the quick response. Very clear explanation!

Comment: @justthom8 It returns a _pointer_ to a structure in this case, although it is also possible to return an actual structure value.